# jquery-ui Sortable ul elements wonky repositioning upon dragging inline elements with x-axis sorting

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have this code set up: http://jsfiddle.net/DZK9M/1/ .

HTML

```
<ul id="sortable" style="list-style: none;">
    <li style="display: inline;" id="dvi_138504">COMPUTER 138504</li>
    <li style="display: inline;" id="dvi_133456">COMPUTER 133456</li>
    <li style="display: inline;" id="dvi_133457">COMPUTER 133457</li>
</ul>Query string: <span id="query"></span> 
<br>Result: <span id="result"></span>
<br>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul').sortable({
        axis: 'x',
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            var data = $(this).sortable('toArray');
            $('#query').text(data);
        }
    });
});
```

If you run it, and drag one of the three items slowly back and forth on the x-axis, the other two sometimes go above and below the item you're dragging. If you drag it slowly back and forth, it even flickers like crazy. Is there a way to prevent this behavior and keep the items on the same line, splitting up when the item you're dragging goes between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this behavior by setting your #sortable style to `overflow: auto` and your li styles to `float: left` instead of `display: inline`

Here's an update to your code showing the change:
http://jsfiddle.net/A474W/